# Почему после сохранения виджета в wordpress мой js код перестает работать?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Привет всем! У меня проблемка. Я создал виджет, добавил инпуты и селекты. В первом селекте я получаю сайт из мультисайта, после этого сохраняю, и у меня в след. селекте появляюся категории с этого сайта, выбираю категорию, после этого снова сохранение, и в след. селекте посты из категории. Всё прогружается только после кнопки save, соответственно. Я набросал скриптик на js, который бы сразу при change вытаскивал всё без надобности в кнопки save, чтобы сразу видеть изменения. Он работает, сохраняет с нужными данными, но как только я нажимаю save, то всё, больше скрипт не работает, как будто мой js становится недоступным, почему так происходит, кто знает ответ?

```
$( '#widget-glenbrook_sites_widget1-2-site' ).on( 'change', function() {
    $( '#widget-glenbrook_sites_widget1-2-savewidget' ).click();
} );

$( '#widget-glenbrook_sites_widget1-2-category' ).on( 'change', function() {
    $( '#widget-glenbrook_sites_widget1-2-savewidget' ).click();
} );
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZJBPX - тут весь код вместе с PHP

Comment: PHP запихивать в codepen смысла никакого, тем более, что он тут и ни при чем. Нужен сгенерированный им html и js.

Comment: Какие обработчики висят на save?